# Insert audio file in web page

Tags: html, audio, ogg

I want to insert an audio file in my web page. I have the .mp3, but not the .ogg, so my audio won't play. What can I do to insert that file?
I have the following code:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="Viva-la-vida.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Please correct me if I said something wrong. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you mentioned is working great with .mp3 file. You can do two things.

1. Check the path you specified in the src attribute for the .mp3 file.
2. Run your .html file in different browsers.

Comment: It doesn't work in any browser(Opera, Chrome, Safari, Mozilla, IE, ...), and the path is correct.

Comment: can you hear the sound here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all

Comment: If you can hear then every thing is good with the hardware, i suspect the file saved on your computer is bad.

Comment: Are there any other ways to insert an audio file? I don't know anything else, and I kinda need this...